# Reopen Votes tests

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-audits

Today I failed twice on [Reopen Votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) tests in the Review area (I've done approx. 900 votes so far)

I've always assumed that the *close* is a true fact and that the tests force me to think about whether the *reopen vote* is justified.

Now it seems that even the fact that the question is closed might only be a test.

Personally, I do think that this is a "strange" way of testing me as a reviewer, so **my suggestion** is to limit reopen vote tests to actually closed questions and not include open questions.

*(For both my failed tests, I would also disagree that the questions should be kept open)*

Comment: all the audits (probably except for suggested edits) have two faces: "known good" and "known bad", expecting opposite outcomes to pass

Comment: Thanks, @gnat. Then the Reopen Votes tests have more than two faces IMHO, because they not only are "a good reopen vote" and "a bad reopen vote" but they might also be "not even a closed question".

Comment: my understanding is, [audit selection algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196949/request-for-review-close-reopen-known-good-audits) for "a good reopen vote" picks only questions that were never closed. I guess this is because previously closed questions are considered "unsafe" (for _automated_ selection), even when these were made into a perfect shape - algorithm is likely not good enough to properly evaluate "shape"

Answer (score 2):

Why?

The review is designed to see whether you can tell if a question was incorrectly closed as well as if it was correctly closed.

You are *supposed* to think when reviewing.

Comment: Isn't that what [Close Votes](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close) is for?

Comment: I just experienced a "Reopen Vote" test, and I got misled  by the fact _there was no changes_, so I thought "why reopening an unchanged question?" → `leave closed`.